# Kohana model constructor with parameter

Tags: php, constructor, kohana

I have model where i am trying to set $_db_group value in constructor to change default database bu it is not working.

My constructor:

```
public function __construct($db)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_db_group=$db;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$_db_group` looks like a local variable, if you want to set the value of a attribute you have to use `$this->_db_group`.
If it's static: `static::$_db_group`

Comment: Of course there is $this->_db_group. I have tried to do this in different ways and i pasted wrong version.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i have found the answer.

```
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->_db_group=$db;
    parent::__construct();
}
```

The value assignment has to be before calling parent constructor